# How to install perf on kernel 5.11 Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: 20.04, kernel

I recently had to update my kernel to be able to use a graphics card. Now I want to use perf but it is not installed. I'm getting the following message:

```
You may need to install the following packages for this specific kernel:
    linux-tools-5.11.0-051100-generic
    linux-cloud-tools-5.11.0-051100-generic
```

When trying to install these packages, however, I get the following messages:

```
E: Unable to locate package linux-tools-5.11.0-051100-generic
E: Couldn't find any package by glob 'linux-tools-5.11.0-051100-generic'
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'linux-tools-5.11.0-051100-generic'
```

and

```
E: Unable to locate package linux-cloud-tools-5.11.0-051100-generic
E: Couldn't find any package by glob 'linux-cloud-tools-5.11.0-051100-generic'
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'linux-cloud-tools-5.11.0-051100-generic'
```

Where can I find/how do I add these packages?

Comment: Use `apt-cache search linux-tools` and `apt-cache search linux-cloud-tools` to see which versions are available.

Comment: 5.11 is not among the versions. Can I use another version or is there a way to get the 5.11 version specifically?

Comment: What OS & release are you using?   5.11 is not a *focal* kernel except for *testing* purposes, but is used by non-Ubuntu OSes.

Comment: Library versions below 5.11 will not provide all the features that version of  `perf` needs. Library versions above 5.11 will probably work. Use the closest higher, if a available. Otherwise, you could build `perf` from source.

Comment: @guiverc I'm using Ubuntu 20.04 I'm not entirely sure, but without this kernel, my graphics card doesn't seem to work. I've picked the version that said stable. How do you know whether a kernel is a focal kernel?

Comment: @waltinator I will try the 5.12 mainline

Comment: Ubuntu 20.04 LTS using the GA kernel will use 5.4, the HWE choice currently is 5.8 or the *groovy* 20.10 kernel when it reached 20.04.2; HWE follows the kernel process of the standard releases; it'll get *hirsute* which is 5.11 on 19-August-2021 according to the current schedule with 20.04.3 (https://wiki.ubuntu.com/FocalFossa/ReleaseSchedule).  5.11 is the current *hirsute* kernel which is still in testing, due for release later this month.